# Sind Berufsbezeichnungen genderneutral?

Tags: gender, gender-neutrality

In der Genderdebatte ist die grundsätzliche Annahme der "Feminist*innen", dass Berufsbezeichnungen oder sonstige wie z.B. Lehrer, Arzt, Student; nur das männliche Geschlecht meinen.

In der Gesellschaft ist dies denke ich nicht mehr unbedingt der Fall, aber was sagen Sprachwissenschaftler dazu? Sind diese Wörter tatsächlich nur die Männer gemeint, kann man das historisch überhaupt festlegen?

Oder ist es so, dass das Wort "Arzt" selbst nichts über das Geschlecht des Arztes*der Ärztin aussagt und tatsächlich genderneutral ist.

Comment: Die als feministisch charakterisierte Position ist falsch dargestellt (schon [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feministische_Linguistik#Formgleichheit_von_generischem_und_spezifischem_Maskulinum_%E2%80%93_unklares_Genus-Sexus-Verh%C3%A4ltnis) ist weitaus differenzierter). Die Frage geht über das Sprachliche hinaus, insofern als geschlechtergerechte Sprache eine gesellschaftliche Aufgabe ist, die nicht durch ein wissenschaftliches Urteil gelöst werden kann. Den letzten Absatz könnte man als sprachliche Frage gelten lassen, ich stimme trotzdem vorerst für die Schließung.

Comment: Kannst du genauer sagen, was du mit "meinen" meinst? Die Frage, was mit dem Wort _gemeint_ ist, ist von der Frage, was das Wort _bedeutet_ verschieden. Dieses Missverständnis ist auch eines der Probleme in der Debatte um gendergerechte Sprache, denke ich :)

Comment: Bitte in diesem Zusammenhang berücksichtigen: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1340/wie-k%c3%b6nnen-wir-den-themenbereich-um-geschlechtergerechte-sprache-objektiv-halten

Answer (score 5):

Was "gemeint" ist, ist eine Frage der Sprecher*innenintention. Das ist also eine subjektive Frage, und lässt sich daher nicht klären; Sprecher*innen können nur jeweils selbst wissen, was sie mit ihren Äußerungen meinen.

Die Kritik am generischen Maskulinum bezieht sich in der Regel nicht auf die (nicht objektiv feststellbare) *Intention*, sondern auf die *Wirkung* der Sprache. Dazu gibt es in der Tat eine Fülle von Studien, welche hier darzustellen den Rahmen dieses Forums sprengen würde. Die Grundeinsicht ist tatsächlich, dass die Verwendung des Maskulinums in der Regel dazu führt, dass Frauen sich statistisch gesehen weniger angesprochen oder gemeint fühlen. Die Befunde sind aber deutlich detaillierter, allgemein kann man sagen, dass der Kontext einen Einfluss auf diese Befunde hat. Wenn dich die Details interessieren, fang zum Beispiel mal mit dem [Wikipedia-Artikel über feministische Linguistik](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feministische_Linguistik#Formgleichheit_von_generischem_und_spezifischem_Maskulinum_%E2%80%93_unklares_Genus-Sexus-Verh%C3%A4ltnis) an.

---

Oftmals vorgebrachte Gegenargumente gegen eine gendergerechte Sprachverwendung, die sich auf die vermeintliche Trennung von Genus und Sexus im Deutschen (à la "Das grammatische Geschlecht hat mit dem natürlichen nichts zu tun.") stützen, gehen an dieser Kritik vorbei.

Erstens sind sie empirisch widerlegt: Wenn die Rezipient*innen es häufiger so wahrnehmen, dass Frauen im generischen Maskulinum nicht angesprochen werden, dann sind Genus und Sexus konzeptuell eben *nicht* voneinander völlig getrennt. Das ist auch schon allein wegen der Natur der Aktivierung von Konzepten im linguistischen Gedächtnis nicht verwunderlich: Das Hören von Homophonen aktiviert immer beide Konzepte. Das bedeutet, dass beim Hören des generischen Maskulinums immer die Bedeutung, dass es sich ausschließlich um Männer handelt, mitaktiviert wird. Selbst wenn gelernt worden ist, dass dabei auch Frauen mitgemeint sein können, ist dennoch zusätzlicher mentaler Aufwand nötig, um diese Ambiguität aufzulösen.

Zweitens zeigt eine etwas genauere linguistische Betrachtung, dass die Aussage nur stimmt, wenn man sie sehr allgemein hält. Je konkreter man sich die Frage von Personenbezeichnungen ansieht, desto mehr erweist sich die Aussage der "Sexus-Blindheit" des grammatischen Genus als falsch:

Schon bei Tieren bildet das Deutsche sexus-definitive Bezeichnungen:  *der Kater*, *der Erpel*, usw. usf. In diesen Bezeichnungen werden also Sexus und Genus miteinander verknüpft.

Gerade bei Personenbezeichnungen sind nun aber Genus und Sexus stark miteinander verknüpft. Hier stimmen, ganz konträr zu der Behauptung, Genus und Sexus *in der Regel* überein: *die Frau*, *der Mann*, *die Nonne*, *der Mönch*, *die Braut*, *der Bräutigam*, und auch bei allen Verwandtschaftsbezeichnungen. *Das Mädchen* ist hier keine Ausnahme, weil es als Diminutiv Neutrum ist, so wie *das Mütterchen* oder *das Onkelchen*. Damit bleibt *das Weib* wohl als einzige Ausnahme von dieser Regel, möglicherweise gibt es hier etymologische Gründe. Das ändert nichts am Regelcharakter der Korrelation von Sexus und Genus bei Personenbezeichnungen.

Genus und Sexus stimmen auch bei allen Funktions- und Berufsbezeichnungen überein, die mit der Endung *-in* aus der maskulinen Form gebildet werden: *die Bäckerin*, *die EU-Kommissions-Präsidentin*, *die Lehrerin*, *die Verbrecherin*. Wären Genus und Sexus völlig unabhängig, dann wäre eine solche Bildung sprachhistorisch gar nicht notwendig (und systematisch auch gar nicht möglich) gewesen.

Ein weiterer Beleg für die Korrelation von Genus und Sexus ist die Tatsache, dass rein weibliche Gruppen nicht mit generischem Maskulinum angesprochen werden, sondern mit der femininen Bezeichnung. Würde das generische Maskulinum tatsächlich als sexusblind angesehen, dann wäre das nicht der Fall.

Damit zeichnet sich eher das Bild, dass das generische Maskulinum bei Berufs- und Funktionsbezeichnungen historisch bedingt ist und daher rührt, dass diese Berufe und Funktionen von Männern ausgeführt wurden; Berufe und Funktionen, die von Frauen ausgeführt wurden, bekamen eine Bezeichnung mit femininem Genus. Ein gutes Beispiel dafür ist das Wort *Krankenschwester*: Hier wurde eine feminine Berufsbezeichnung gewählt, weil praktisch alle Krankenschwestern weiblichen Geschlechts waren. Seitdem es auch verstärkt männliche Krankenschwestern gibt, hat sich für diese der Begriff *Krankenpfleger* etabliert. Das zeigt, dass Genus und Sexus in der gelebten Sprachrealität durchaus miteinander verknüpft werden; bei einer Sexus-Blindheit der sprachlichen Bezeichnungen würde sich wohl einfach die Bezeichnung *Krankenschwester* auch für das männliche Pflegepersonal eingebürgert haben.

Es ist also gar nicht klar, was die Aussage "Genus und Sexus sind im Deutschen getrennt" überhaupt bedeuten soll. Sie ist weder empirisch noch sprachsystematisch haltbar. Man kann sie allenfalls als *logische* Aussage verstehen: Die Begriffe *Genus* und *Sexus* sind logisch voneinander verschieden. Für die Frage nach der Gendergerechten Sprachverwendung ist aber ein *systematischer* oder ein *statistischer* Zusammenhang relevant, und beide sind bei Personenbezeichnungen gegeben.

Comment: Bemerkenswert, wie falsch man die Befunde interpretieren kann. Ich will nur zwei, drei davon kurz bestreiten. Der Diminutiv Mädchen - hat den jemand mit Waffengewalt der dt. Sprache aufgezwungen? Fiel der Begriff aus dem göttlichen Sprachhimmel? Wenn es eine so enge Bindung wie von Dir behauptet gäbe, dann hätte sich entweder der Begriff "Mädchen" gar nicht etabliert, weil er der eingefleischten Empfindung, keine heranwachsende Frau bezeichnen zu können, zuwider gelaufen wäre oder die Sprache hätte da eine Ausnahme mehr gemacht, und es hieße "die Mädchen" (singular).

Comment: Du kommst allen Ernstes mit einem Kater an? Ist Dir schon mal aufgefallen, dass es allüberall Katzenstreu und Katzenfutter zu kaufen gibt, aber nirgends Katerfutter und Katerstreu? Weil hier Katze die generische Form ist. Sie bezeichnet sowohl den Allgemeinfall des Katzentiers ohne Betrachtung des Geschlechts als auch weibliche Katzen. Will man diese ausdrücklich sexuell hervorheben muss man "weibliche Katze" sagen, wie bei "männlicher Berufskraftfahrer".

Comment: Punkt 3 noch, dann hör ich auf: Es beschränkt sich überhaupt nicht auf Berufe oder Funktionen, die früher ausschließlich von Männern ausgeübt wurden (Papst, Richter, Schmied, Krieger) sondern ist bei völlig geschlechtsunspezifischen Tätigkeiten genauso: der Schläfer, der Esser, der Fußgänger. Es ist unabhängig von der Frage eines zeitweiligen Ausschlusses von Frauen aus Berufs- und Tätigkeitsfeldern in der Sprache homogen gleich, weshalb das Argument nicht greifen kann.

Comment: Punkt 4 muss noch sein. Jmd. arbeitet in einem Kongresshotel, es findet ein Psychologenkongress und ein Erzieherkongress statt mit Vorträgen in Sälen und Workshops in kleineren Räumen und er kommst aus Raum E7.2 und sein Kollege fragt: "Wer ist da so laut." Derjenige weiß, es sind 5 Frauen im Raum, die zum Psychologiekongress gehören und antwortet "Die Psychologen". Das ist tadellos in Ordnung. Auch homogen weibliche Gruppen kann man geschlechtsneutral mit dem gen. Mask. darstellen, wenn man eben vom Geschlecht absieht. Es könnte etwa sein, dass es bei den Psychologen immer etwas laut ist.

Comment: Oh, das ist ein Missverständnis: _der Kater_ war doch lediglich ein Beleg dafür, dass Genus und Sexus nicht getrennt sind. Es ist eben gerade kein Zufall, dass die Bezeichnung einer Katze mit männlichem Sexus ebenfalls männliches Genus hat. Wer davon ausgeht, dass Genus und Sexus völlig unabhängig sind, müsste das aber glauben. Das Beispiel soll nur aufweisen, dass Genus und Sexus eben doch in einer systematischen und nicht in einer arbiträren Beziehung zueinander stehen.

Comment: Niemand hat eine arbiträre Beziehung behauptet. Die Behauptung ist, dass die sprachlich maskuline Form in "der Brite, der Koch, der Fußgänger" nichts über das Geschlecht aussagt. Wenn man einen männlichen Briten, Koch oder Fußgänger als männlich kennzeichnen will, muss man das dazusagen, außer natürlich, es wurde bereits vorher gesagt oder kann aus anderen Gründen als bekannt vorausgesetzt werden. Köchin dagegen kann nur eine Frau bezeichnen und betont, dass es sich um eine Frau handelt. Es hängt aber an den Wörtern, nicht am biol. Geschlecht, wie man an Katzenfutter und der Mausefalle sieht.

Answer (score 3):

Im Prinzip ja.

Sprachwissenschaftlich herrscht der Grundsatz, dass eine Trennung zwischen Genus (dem grammatischen Geschlecht) und Sexus (dem biologischen Geschlecht) besteht. Der Baum hat genausowenig zwingend ein männliches biologisches Geschlecht wie der Arzt.

Aus verschiedenen Gründen wird in Teilen der Bevölkerung dieser Unterschied nicht sauber wahrgenommen. Das hat zum Gender Mainstreaming geführt. Und dazu, dass einige zwischen einem Arzt und einer Ärztin unterschieden wissen wollen. In einer Welt mit mehr als zwei geschlechtlichen Identitäten führt dieser Weg gerade in eine Sackgasse.

Sich sprachlich wieder auf diese Trennung zu besinnen, ist einer Handreichung für die Frauenbeauftragte der Uni München sinnvoll: [Handreichung](https://www.frauenbeauftragte.uni-muenchen.de/frauenbeauftr/berichte/berichte_veranstalt/handreichung2007.pdf)

Comment: Die Handreichung ist in der Tat lesenswert.